# Inconsistency when estimating AR model coefficients in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, autoregressive-models

I'm trying to estimate the coefficients of an AR[2] model

```
x(t) = a_1*x(t-1) + a_2*x(t-2) + e(t), e(t) ~ N(0, sigma^2)
```

in MATLAB. For `a_1 = 2*cos(2*pi/T)*exp(-1/tau), a_2 = -exp(-2/tau)`, the AR[2] model corresponds to a linear damped oscillator with period T and relaxation time `tau`. I simulated some data for this process with `T = 30` and `tau = 100` which corresponds to `a_1 = 1.9368, a_2 = -0.9802`:

```
T = 30; tau = 100;
a_1 = 2*cos(2*pi/T)*exp(-1/tau); a_2 = -exp(-2/tau);

simuMdl = arima(2,0,0);
simuMdl.Constant = 0;
simuMdl.Variance = 1e-1;
simuMdl.AR{1} = a_1;
simuMdl.AR{2} = a_2;

data = simulate(simuMdl, 600);
data = data(501:end);
plot(data)
```

[image: link to plot of the simulated data]

I only take the last 100 timepoints to make sure the system is not influenced by the initial conditions any more. Now, when trying to estimate the parameters, everything works just fine when using the `estimate` command that uses maximum likelihood estimation:

```
ToEstMdl = arima(2,0,0); ToEstMdl.Constant = 0;
EstMdl = estimate(ToEstMdl, data);
EstMdl.AR
%'[1.9319]    [-0.9745]'
```

However, when I use the Yule-Walker-Equations implemented in `aryule`, I get a completely different result that does not match the true parameter values at all:

```
aryule(data, 2)
%'1.0000   -1.4645    0.5255'
```

Does anyone have an idea why the Yule-Walker-equations have such shortcomings to the MLE approach?

Comment: On the first glance I would guess this behavior is connected to the assumptions of the model. First of all, the aryule the coefficents go form 0 to p, by contrast to the arima assumption where the AR model looks only in to the past not including the current sample so the coefficients go from 1 to p. This limitations will clearly have an influence on the result, but that is just a guess

Answer (score 0):

Yule-Walker (YW) is a method of moment based method. As such its estimate would get better with increasing data points. You can check it in this example by using all 600 data points to see what is the 'best' YW estimate you can get had you used all the data points and the MLE would still be better than it. You can also increase the data points to say 5000 instead of 600 and you will see in this case the best YW (the one that uses all 5000 points) would start to approach the MLE estimate.